# Scroll for tbody

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the scroll for tbody but to no luck.

If I put display block to thead and tbody then I am able to achieve the scroll to tbody but then alignment of thead and tbody get's distorted.

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <thead style="background-color: #d9edf7;">
    <tr>
      <th class="info">Line#</th>
      <th class="info">Product</th>
      <th class="info" style="display:{!if(isLApprovedRC,'none','')};">Last Approved <br>MRC</th>
      <th class="info" style="display:{!if(isLApprovedNRC,'none','')};">Last Approved <br>NRC</th>
      <th class="info">Approved MRC</th>
      <th class="info">Approved NRC</th>
      <th class="info" style="display:{!if(UsageVisibleUI,'none','')}">Usage Charge</th>
      <th class="info" style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}">Approved Burst <br>Rate</th>
      <th class="info" style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}">Approved China <br>Burst Rate</th>
      <th class="info" style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">Cost MRC</th>
      <th class="info" style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">Cost NRC</th>
      <th class="info" style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">Margin(%)</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody style="height: 450px;overflow: auto;">
    <tr>
      <td class="info">1</td>
      <td class="info" style="word-wrap:break-word;">Product Informa</td>
      <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedRC,'none','')}"> 100.2</td>
      <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedNRC,'none','')}">100.2</td>
      <td>
        100.2
      </td>
      <td>
        100.2
      </td>

      <td style="display:{!if(UsageVisibleUI,'none','')}">100.2
      </td>
      <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}">
        100.2
      </td>
      <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}">
        100.2
      </td>
      <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
        100.2
      </td>
      <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
        100.2
      </td>
      <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">100.2</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have put this in below fiddle. Kindly help

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3d2sp5au/1/)

Comment: What's this: `style="display:{!if(isLApprovedRC,'none','')};"`? Also, you could make this a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), so we don't even need to go to a different site.

Comment: that is business logic...some th and tr on tbody are conditional....will try this next time onwards... but if you inspect you will see the structure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see below code. You have to add css on `tr` and `tbody` which i have added in code snipeet and remove inline style from table `tbody`

```css
.a th, td{
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid gray; 
}
.a thead th, .a tbody tr{ display:table; width:100%}

tr {
width: 100%;
display: inline-table;
table-layout: fixed;
}

tbody{
  overflow-y: scroll;      
  height: 200px;        /*   <---- Select the height of the body */
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
   <thead style="background-color: #d9edf7;">
   <tr>
     <th class="info">Line#</th>
                    <th class="info">Product</th>
                    <th class="info" style="display:{!if(isLApprovedRC,'none','')};">Last Approved <br>MRC</th>
                    <th class="info" style="display:{!if(isLApprovedNRC,'none','')};">Last Approved <br>NRC</th>
                    <th class="info">Approved MRC</th>
                    <th class="info">Approved NRC</th>
                    <th class="info" style="display:{!if(UsageVisibleUI,'none','')}">Usage Charge</th>
                    <th class="info" style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}">Approved Burst <br>Rate</th>
                    <th class="info" style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}">Approved China <br>Burst Rate</th>
                    <th class="info" style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">Cost MRC</th>
                    <th class="info" style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">Cost NRC</th>
                    <th class="info" style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">Margin(%)</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
           
                <tbody style="">
                    <tr>
                            <td class="info">1</td>
                            <td class="info" style="word-wrap:break-word;">Product Informa</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedRC,'none','')}"> 100.2</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedNRC,'none','')}">100.2</td>
                            <td>
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td>
                         100.2
                            </td>

                            <td style="display:{!if(UsageVisibleUI,'none','')}">100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}"> 
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                             <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td> 
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">100.2</td> 
                            <td></td>                                                       
                        </tr> 
                           <tr>
                            <td class="info">1</td>
                            <td class="info" style="word-wrap:break-word;">Product Informa</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedRC,'none','')}"> 100.2</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedNRC,'none','')}">100.2</td>
                            <td>
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td>
                         100.2
                            </td>

                            <td style="display:{!if(UsageVisibleUI,'none','')}">100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}"> 
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                             <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td> 
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">100.2</td> 
                            <td></td>                                                       
                        </tr> 
                           <tr>
                            <td class="info">1</td>
                            <td class="info" style="word-wrap:break-word;">Product Informa</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedRC,'none','')}"> 100.2</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedNRC,'none','')}">100.2</td>
                            <td>
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td>
                         100.2
                            </td>

                            <td style="display:{!if(UsageVisibleUI,'none','')}">100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}"> 
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                             <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td> 
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">100.2</td> 
                            <td></td>                                                       
                        </tr> 
                           <tr>
                            <td class="info">1</td>
                            <td class="info" style="word-wrap:break-word;">Product Informa</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedRC,'none','')}"> 100.2</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedNRC,'none','')}">100.2</td>
                            <td>
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td>
                         100.2
                            </td>

                            <td style="display:{!if(UsageVisibleUI,'none','')}">100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}"> 
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                             <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td> 
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">100.2</td> 
                            <td></td>                                                       
                        </tr> 
                           <tr>
                            <td class="info">1</td>
                            <td class="info" style="word-wrap:break-word;">Product Informa</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedRC,'none','')}"> 100.2</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedNRC,'none','')}">100.2</td>
                            <td>
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td>
                         100.2
                            </td>

                            <td style="display:{!if(UsageVisibleUI,'none','')}">100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}"> 
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                             <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td> 
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">100.2</td> 
                            <td></td>                                                       
                        </tr> 
                           <tr>
                            <td class="info">1</td>
                            <td class="info" style="word-wrap:break-word;">Product Informa</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedRC,'none','')}"> 100.2</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedNRC,'none','')}">100.2</td>
                            <td>
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td>
                         100.2
                            </td>

                            <td style="display:{!if(UsageVisibleUI,'none','')}">100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}"> 
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                             <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td> 
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">100.2</td> 
                            <td></td>                                                       
                        </tr> 
                           <tr>
                            <td class="info">1</td>
                            <td class="info" style="word-wrap:break-word;">Product Informa</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedRC,'none','')}"> 100.2</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedNRC,'none','')}">100.2</td>
                            <td>
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td>
                         100.2
                            </td>

                            <td style="display:{!if(UsageVisibleUI,'none','')}">100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}"> 
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                             <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td> 
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">100.2</td> 
                            <td></td>                                                       
                        </tr> 
                           <tr>
                            <td class="info">1</td>
                            <td class="info" style="word-wrap:break-word;">Product Informa</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedRC,'none','')}"> 100.2</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedNRC,'none','')}">100.2</td>
                            <td>
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td>
                         100.2
                            </td>

                            <td style="display:{!if(UsageVisibleUI,'none','')}">100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}"> 
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                             <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td> 
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">100.2</td> 
                            <td></td>                                                       
                        </tr> 
                           <tr>
                            <td class="info">1</td>
                            <td class="info" style="word-wrap:break-word;">Product Informa</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedRC,'none','')}"> 100.2</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedNRC,'none','')}">100.2</td>
                            <td>
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td>
                         100.2
                            </td>

                            <td style="display:{!if(UsageVisibleUI,'none','')}">100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}"> 
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                             <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td> 
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">100.2</td> 
                            <td></td>                                                       
                        </tr> 
                           <tr>
                            <td class="info">1</td>
                            <td class="info" style="word-wrap:break-word;">Product Informa</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedRC,'none','')}"> 100.2</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedNRC,'none','')}">100.2</td>
                            <td>
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td>
                         100.2
                            </td>

                            <td style="display:{!if(UsageVisibleUI,'none','')}">100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}"> 
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                             <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td> 
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">100.2</td> 
                            <td></td>                                                       
                        </tr> 
                           <tr>
                            <td class="info">1</td>
                            <td class="info" style="word-wrap:break-word;">Product Informa</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedRC,'none','')}"> 100.2</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedNRC,'none','')}">100.2</td>
                            <td>
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td>
                         100.2
                            </td>

                            <td style="display:{!if(UsageVisibleUI,'none','')}">100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}"> 
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                             <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td> 
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">100.2</td> 
                            <td></td>                                                       
                        </tr> 
                           <tr>
                            <td class="info">1</td>
                            <td class="info" style="word-wrap:break-word;">Product Informa</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedRC,'none','')}"> 100.2</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedNRC,'none','')}">100.2</td>
                            <td>
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td>
                         100.2
                            </td>

                            <td style="display:{!if(UsageVisibleUI,'none','')}">100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}"> 
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                             <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td> 
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">100.2</td> 
                            <td></td>                                                       
                        </tr> 
                           <tr>
                            <td class="info">1</td>
                            <td class="info" style="word-wrap:break-word;">Product Informa</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedRC,'none','')}"> 100.2</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedNRC,'none','')}">100.2</td>
                            <td>
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td>
                         100.2
                            </td>

                            <td style="display:{!if(UsageVisibleUI,'none','')}">100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}"> 
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                             <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td> 
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">100.2</td> 
                            <td></td>                                                       
                        </tr> 
                           <tr>
                            <td class="info">1</td>
                            <td class="info" style="word-wrap:break-word;">Product Informa</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedRC,'none','')}"> 100.2</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedNRC,'none','')}">100.2</td>
                            <td>
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td>
                         100.2
                            </td>

                            <td style="display:{!if(UsageVisibleUI,'none','')}">100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}"> 
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                             <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td> 
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">100.2</td> 
                            <td></td>                                                       
                        </tr> 
                           <tr>
                            <td class="info">1</td>
                            <td class="info" style="word-wrap:break-word;">Product Informa</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedRC,'none','')}"> 100.2</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedNRC,'none','')}">100.2</td>
                            <td>
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td>
                         100.2
                            </td>

                            <td style="display:{!if(UsageVisibleUI,'none','')}">100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}"> 
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                             <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td> 
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">100.2</td> 
                            <td></td>                                                       
                        </tr> 
                           <tr>
                            <td class="info">1</td>
                            <td class="info" style="word-wrap:break-word;">Product Informa</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedRC,'none','')}"> 100.2</td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isLApprovedNRC,'none','')}">100.2</td>
                            <td>
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td>
                         100.2
                            </td>

                            <td style="display:{!if(UsageVisibleUI,'none','')}">100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}"> 
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(isVisible1,'none','')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td>
                             <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">
                           100.2
                            </td> 
                            <td style="display:{!if(IsAccessible,'','none')}">100.2</td> 
                            <td></td>                                                       
                        </tr> 
           
                     
                   
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: thanks bharat for the response.... this certainly helped me. I ran into one more issue is that not tfoot is breaking off post this change.Please find the updated fiddle...https://jsfiddle.net/m35ftwwa/1/

Comment: @Akki619 please check fiddle,  https://jsfiddle.net/bharat_patidar/tcdfayba/  you just need to update this `tfoot > tr{
        margin-top:450px;
    }` css in you page. you can change margin according to your page.